# How to escape multiple &(ampersand) in xml using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am getting more then one time `&` occurred in `<Description>` tag value in xml look like:

```
<str name="Description">Type: Fan & Heatsinks<br/>Compatible CPU: Intel<br/>Heatsink Material: Copper (base and heat-pipes), aluminium (cooling fins), soldered joints & nickel plating<br/></str>
```

i want to escape multiple `&` in xml using XSLT

xslt code look like:

```
<xsl:variable name="Description" select="str[@name = 'ShortDescription']"/>

<Description><xsl:value-of select="$Description" disable-output-escaping="yes"  /></Description>
```

i am getting this error on `&`

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
```

pls give me idea how to handle this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is not well-formed XML: `&` must always be escaped as `&amp;`. XSLT cannot handle input data that is not well-formed XML.

The best way to fix bad data is always to correct the program that created it. If you really can't find a way to do that, you will have to write some kind of repair tool, and the details of the repair tool depend on understanding what kind of problems are present in the input. You can't use XML tools for the repair because the input is not XML; you'll have to use something like Perl. (Or if you really want to use XSLT, you could read the input using `unparsed-text()` to bypass the XML parser.)